# Problems with order of attributes of CRS 4326 in R

Tags: r, r-sp, r-maptools

I load a shape file using R *maptools* package

```
Subcat<-readShapeSpatial("Contour500/Catchments500.shp",proj4string = CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))

class(Subcat)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Then I load another shape file

```
load("Temperature/WCAdj.RData")
class(WcT$Geoloc)
[1] "SpatialPoints"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

I want to use the *over* function from *sp* package

```
over(WcT$Geoloc,Subcat)
```

But when I run it I get the next error

```
Error: identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE
```

This is strange as I used the same CRS for both files *CRS('+init=epsg:4326')*. I double checked and found a slight difference in the order of the attributes of the CRS

```
proj4string(Subcat)
[1] "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"

proj4string(WcT$Geoloc)
[1] "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

The only difference is the order of the Attributes (+ellps, +no_defs and +datum), but all values are the same. I solved this by loading again Subcat using

```
Subcat<-readShapeSpatial("Contour500/Catchments500.shp",proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

However I wanted to know if there is another solution as I want to avoid the same error in the future and wanted to know where this error comes from. I checked the details of the CRS definition in (https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf ) and in the SP package documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/sp.pdf  , but they do not give too many details regarding the order of the attributes.

Has anyone had the same issue?

Does anyone know how to avoid this?

Just in case

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
```

…

```
other attached packages:
[1] rgeos_0.3-2     maptools_0.8-27 rgdal_0.8-11    sp_1.0-14
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simpler than i thought, just update all packages. After writing to the author he said that sometimes, when R is updated, old versions of packages may experience this type of problems, thus they require to be updated as well.